# Regex Find Missing Double Bracket tags and remove them

Tags: regex

i have string like this

{wrongTag}} RegExr was {{created}aaaa{{fffffff}} shks {{sdfsdfsd}  and    {{created}aaaa{{fffffff}

i want to remove all wrong tags either single bracket is missing from the start or end of tag. in example about only {{fffffff}} is correct tag all other tags are worng should be removed , my code is this for removing all wrong tags

```
const cleanString = message.replace(/(?!{{[^{{}}]+\}\})\{{[^{{}}]+\}/g, "")
```

but my regex is only detecting last missing baraket .
So following wrong tag also be matched

https://regexr.com/69vlq

{wrongTag}}

{missingtag}

Below is my Regex , you can see its working partially but not fully any help would be appricated

https://regexr.com/69vlq

Comment: You should learn about character classes: This `[^{{}}]` is the same as: `[^{}]` - it matches either of the characters, not the word `{{}}`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```js
const cleanString = message.replace(/(?<!{)({{[^{}]+}})(?!})|{+[^{}]*}+/g, '$1');
```

Or,

```js
const cleanString = message.replace(/((?:[^{]|^){{[^{}]+}}(?:{{[^{}]+}})*)(?!})|{+[^{}]*}+/g, '$1');
```

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/BiZECl/1/) / [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/7x24IA/2). The point is to match and capture into Group 1 any valid tag, and then match and remove the tags with any one or more curly braces around them.

*Details*:

- `(?<!{)` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is a `{` char immediately to the left of the current location
- `({{[^{}]+}})` - Group 1: `{{`, one or more chars other than `{` and `}`, and then `}}`
- `(?!})` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is a `}` char immediately to the right of the current location
- `|` - or
- `{+` - one or more `{` chars
- `[^{}]*` - zero or more chars other than `{` and `}`
- `}+` - one or more `}` chars.

In the no-lookbehind solution, `(?<!{)` is replaced with `(?:[^{]|^)` that matches either a char other than `{` (with `[^{]`) or start of string (with `^`).

Comment: @AzharMuhammad This is why there is regex #2 with no lookbehind.

Comment: Great but 
https://regex101.com/r/7x24IA/1 
see this case is failing .
{{yyyyy}} should not be removed as its valid tag

Comment: @AzharMuhammad Use https://regex101.com/r/7x24IA/2 then

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for mismatched brackets, you could use the following test for missing leading brackets

```
[^{]{([^{}]+)\}\}
```

and this for missing trailing brackets

```
{{([^{}]+)\}[^}]
```

and this for missing leading and trailing brackets

```
[^{]{([^{}]+)\}[^}]
```

It can by done with a single regex; but you're well on your way to write only code when you try to make a regular expression do more than a single operation at a time.

In plain english; the first expression would read:
Find the first '{' that is not preceded by a '{'.  Match a group of characters that do not contain '{' or '}' until you reach a '}' followed by another '}'

The second is basically the same statement, but it reads:
Find the first "{{". Match a group of characters that do not contain '{' or '}' and consider it a match if the next '}' is not followed by '}'.

The third is just a combination of the first two, to match items that are wrapped in "{}" but not in "{{}}"

Comment: {currentCompany}} hi  {{firstName}} {{lastName}}
try this one it will not clean first wrong tag "{currentCompany}}"